# To make a .xls file from the extracted values from a website

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am an absolute beginner in Python Programming and that too Web Scraping.
I was trying to scrape a website for practice purpose.

I have used the BeautifulSoup and Requests module.

The code is given below:

```
import requests
import xlwt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

response=requests.get("https://www.wikipedia.org/")
wb=xlwt.Workbook()
ws=wb.add_sheet("Test")
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
links=soup.find_all("strong")
for link in links:
    lang=link.get_text()
    for i in len(lang):
        ws.write(i,i,lang)
        wb.save("Wiki.xls")
```

I have scraped the headings from the web page but at the time of writing it to a excel file the following error is displayed.

```
File "C:/Users/laptop/PycharmProjects/myproject/srapingex1.py", line 16, in <module>
    for i in len(str(lang)):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The main problem is that the syntax of `ws.write(row,column,data)` requires the row address, column address and the data.

As I do not know the predefined size of the list, so how can be the row, column address be passed.

Please tell if I am doing the code incorrectly and kindly suggest if there is any way to write the extracted items onto a .xls file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using pandas and write to csv. You can preserve the language format nicely as well

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get('https://www.wikipedia.org/')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
items  = [item.text for item in soup.select('strong')][1:-1]
df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns = ['Languages']) 
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Wiki.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

---

You could write to xls with `df.to_excel`

```
df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Wiki.xls", sheet_name='MyData', index = False, header=False)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190891/discussion-on-answer-by-qharr-to-make-a-xls-file-from-the-extracted-values-from).